# Can't set ItemTemplate to ListView because it doesn't find the resource

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

This is my ListDictionary.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Seminarska">

<DataTemplate x:Name="ArticleListTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                   Margin="5"
                   Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And my MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="Seminarska.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Seminarska"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ProgressRing HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Visibility="Collapsed"
                  Height="100"
                  Width="100"
                  x:Name="pbLoading"
                  Grid.RowSpan="3" />

    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Margin="10,0,0,0"
               Text="My articles"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

    <ListView x:Name="lvData"
              Grid.Row="1"
              SelectionChanged="LvData_OnSelectionChanged"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ArticleListTemplate}"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

As you can see I am trying to set ItemTemplate to ListView but it doesn't find it. It says:

> The resource 'ArticleListTemplate' could not be resolved.

Comment: where do you import/use ListDictionary?

Comment: Ah...I don't. I'm completely new to Windows Phone development. Could you let me know how I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you did not do that in application resources for example in order to access resources from dictionary file you need to use it first

```
<Page>
   <Page.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary >
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/path/to/file/ListDictionary.xaml"/>
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      </ResourceDictionary>
   </Page.Resources>
   <!--  -->
</Page>
```

and for `DataTemplate` you need to use [`x:Key`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt204787.aspx) instead of `x:Name`

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ArticleListTemplate">
```

Comment: Yes, that was it :) Thanks!